# RMS Radius of $N$-Body Simulation

Tags: astrophysics, computational-physics, simulations, star-clusters

I am trying to simulate a globular cluster and investigating the root-mean-square radius of the system as it evolves. I want to ignore particles which are "lost" from the system.

However, when trying to calculate the rms radius of the system, I have come up with 2 approaches:

1. Ignore all particles outside of a given radius. – The problem I have with this is that the system moves as a whole in a certain direction so eventually no particles are included in the calculation.
2. Ignoring particles with a velocity > escape velocity of the system. – I have the issue here of some particles being flung out very far yet still being gravitationally bound to the system and returning dominating the rms calculation.
   As shown in the gif attached the body moves down as a whole. Is there a way I would be able to find the centre of mass of just this system rather than the system as a whole (black dot) which I could then use to exclude particles outside of a given radius from the CoM of this body?

The body does only move in the z-direction so I could potentially ignore particles with an x or y magnitude greater than a certain value, but then have the issue of this not always being the same when I later change the configuration of the system (e.g particles of different mass/different starting positions

[image: Gif of system]

Comment: You could avoid the initial slingshot effect by providing a random (tangential?) velocity to each particle. Currently it seems that all particles start with zero velocity.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, this is what I am trying to investigate! - The evolution of a system of n-bodies generated in a sphere with 0 initial velocities.

Comment: Have you "damped" your inverse square force so that you don't have sudden "unphysical" jumps when the origins of two or more bodies coincide?

Comment: Yes, I have included a softening factor in my force calculations.

Comment: One idea could be to divide space into a grid, and define a "density" (number of particles per grid box). The "maximum" of this density would be somewhere in the big cluster, and you could find the coordinates of that point, and then ignore all grid points beyond a certain distance from it that are lower than some reference density.

Comment: If you remove parts of your system you also remove the property you are trying to investigate. So maybe you should rethink the initial conditions or the question you want to answer with this simulation?

Comment: It is in the nature of globular clusters to lose bodies over time and seeing as I am running a simulation only using 100 particles, the effect of the loss of these particles is very significant.